# What did Paul call Christians?

Tags: paul, pauline-epistles, terminology

*(For this question please assume that Paul considered himself a Christian and that he was the author of all 13 canonical Pauline letters.)*

My question is: what terms (or phrases) did Paul use most frequently in referring to Christians? I am guessing he didn't call them "Christians."

Some possibilities (to give you an idea of what I mean) might be:

- brothers
- elect (of God)
- believers

I would like the top 3 terms that he uses with some sort of figure indicating how often he used it relative to other terms.

Comment: Another possibility I just thought of might be "spiritual men"

Comment: Frequently in his opening greetings, 'saints'.

Comment: In Acts 22:4, he calls them "followers of this way" and uses that as a name for Christians in 24:14 ("However, I admit that I worship the God of our ancestors as a follower of the Way, which they call a sect."). Jesus had identified himself as "the Way" (John 14:6) and the name appears throughout Acts (9:2; 11:26; 19:9, 23; 22:4; 24:14, 22; see 18:25, 26 for the similar terms "the Way of the Lord" and "the way of God"). Luke seems to have liked it. However, Paul does not use that term in the Epistles.

Comment: I did a search for the word christian and found this “The disciples were called Christians first at Antioch.” — https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Acts+11:26&version=NIV (I was told that christian appears 3 or 4 times, but I only found this one). Also “followers of the way” disciple means follower.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OP's interest in quantifying Paul's (or, if you like, the NT's Pauline tradition) most frequently used designations for "Christians" makes for a challenging question, and one that would take a long time to deal with definitively.

Here is my best shot. Methodology: I have tabulated the figures for the thirteen NT letters in the "Pauline tradition", using the designations discussed by Paul Trebilco, *[Self-designations and Group Identity in the New Testament](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=eClpyHjVJg0C&printsec=frontcover)* (Cambridge University Press, 2011). In his introduction ([p. 3](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=eClpyHjVJg0C&lpg=PP1&pg=PA3#v=onepage&q&f=false)), he outlines them thus:

[image: trebilco page 3]

Here are the figures:

```
                  +----+----+----+----+---+---+
                  | A  | B  | C  | D  | E | F |  
+-----------------+----+----+----+----+---+---+
| Romans          | 13 |  5 |  9 |  6 |   | 1 |
| 1 Corinthians   | 27 | 22 |  7 |  3 |   |   |
| 2 Corinthians   |  7 |  9 |  5 |    |   |   |
| Galatians       | 10 |  3 |    |  1 |   |   |
| Ephesians       |  1 |  9 | 11 |  1 | 1 |   |
| Philippians     |  8 |  2 |  2 |    |   |   |
| Colossians      |  2 |  4 |  6 |    | 1 | 1 |
| 1 Thessalonians | 17 |  2 |  1 |  3 |   |   |
| 2 Thessalonians |  7 |  2 |  1 |    |   |   |
| 1 Timothy       |  3 |  3 |  1 |    | 5 |   |
| 2 Timothy       |  2 |    |    |    | 1 | 1 |
| Titus           |    |    |    |    | 1 | 1 |
| Philemon        |    |  1 |  2 |    |   |   |
+-----------------+----+----+----+----+---+---+
| TOTAL           | 97 | 62 | 45 | 14 | 9 | 4 |
+-----------------+----+----+----+----+---+---+
```

*Legend*
A - brothers and sisters (ἀδελφοί)
B - assembly (ἐκκλησία)
C - saints (ἅγιοι)
D - believers (πιστεύοντες)
E - believers (πιστοί)
F - elect (ἐκλεκτός) ***n.b.*** NOT one of Trebilco's terms
*n.b. - blanks = 0*

**Notes**: (obvioulsy) arranged left-to-right in order of decreasing frequency. I have included the 0's (blanks) to make clear the comparison. But I have **omitted** the following:
   - disciples (μαθηταί);
   - way (ὁδός); and
   - christians (Χριστιανός).
as they are all "zeroes" for these thirteen books. Trebilco (it will be noted) combines the categories I have separated out as "D" and "E", as the distribution seemed interesting here between the Catholic and Pastoral epistles. There is some element of "judgment call" in D/E, so those interested should do the search/concordance work for themselves.

Do consult Trebilco's substantial book for further information. A bit of additional relevant bibliography:

- Tim Hegedus, "[Naming Christians in Antiquity](http://sir.sagepub.com/content/33/2/173.short)", *Studies in Religion/Sciences Religieuses* 33 (2004): 173-190.
- Judith Lieu, *[Neither Jew Nor Greek?: Constructing Early Christianity](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=YfaCYeIZ6F8C)* (A & C Black, 2005).

There is, of course, much more, but hopefully this responds adequately to OP's interest.

Comment: Great info! Realizing the books vary in length (some normalization based on length would be interesting), it is still intriguing to see the emphasis of ἐκκλησία for the Corinthians (35% in 1 Cor, 50% adding 2 Cor) dealing with issues of their assembly (1 Cor 1:10-17). Additionally, 35% of the uses of ἀδελφοί were in those two books also, as he tried to emphasize unity. Other similar things jump out: 24% of ἅγιοι in Eph, which deals with being and living sanctified, 18% of ἀδελφοί in 1 Thes with a church Paul had to leave quickly (Act 17:1-10, 1 Thes 2:17), showing his attachment and care.

Comment: @ScottS - yes, plenty of interest in there. The thought about "normalizing" crossed my mind, but Q is about overall preference/frequency, and that isn't affected by "weighting". But yes, the distribution has some quite fascinating facets! E.g., One wonders in 1 Thess also whether the ἀδελφοί language is *cementing* what was still a very freshly forged "familial" relationship.

Comment: Only math is perfect, so that was a perfect answer.