Do we inherit the name of Christ?
Generally from passages like Romans 8:17 (ESV):

and if children, then heirs—heirs of God and fellow heirs with
Christ, provided we suffer with him in order that we may also be
glorified with him.

It is commonly interpreted that we inherit everything Christ inherits. Yet verses like Hebrews 1:4 (ESV) state:

having become as much superior to angels as the name he has inherited
is more excellent than theirs.

And that name is described in Philippians 2:9-11 (ESV):

Therefore God has highly exalted him and bestowed on him the name that
is above every name, 10 so that at the name of Jesus every knee should
bow, in heaven and on earth and under the earth, 11 and every tongue
confess that Jesus Christ is Lord, to the glory of God the Father.

and Revelations 19:16 (ESV) says:

On his robe and on his thigh he has a name written, King of kings and
Lord of lords.

those who hold that we inherit everything Christ inherits, does that not then mean we inherit the name "King of kings and Lord of lords" at which every knee shall bow? Would that not be in conflict with verses like Isaiah 42:8?

I am the Lord; that is my name;
my glory I give to no other,
nor my praise to carved idols.

Note: An answer I have heard is that we have the right to call upon the name - which I agree with - but that is distinct from inheriting it, because just because we can use it does not mean it is ours.

That seems to me to be a false interpretation of Romans 8:17. We may be fellow heirs, but it doesn't logically follow that we are equal heirs of Jesus. Even at a human level we know how all family members may inherit from a will, but the terms of that inheritance may vary depending on the terms of the will.

Followers of Christ are called "Christians" and thus take the name of Christ; but we are NOT equal to Christ.

@Dottard So in what sense do you think we take the name? Is it in the sense that we bear it to show we belong to Christ? Or is it that the name becomes our name as much as it is Christ's?

We, as Christians, take the Name of Christ and are supposed to be imitators of Christ

@Dottard right, but in what sense do we take the name of Christ? If we take on the name to the same degree that Christ inherits the name, that is tantamount to saying Rev. 19:6 & Phil. 2:9-11 can apply to us just as it does Christ.

I have jsy answered that question!  We take the name of Christ by imitating Christ.  We love as He loved.  We are kind as He is kind.  We forgive as He forgave; We are persecuted as He was persecuted.  We teach what He taught, etc.

@Dottard Well it sounded like you were taking the first option, I wasn't sure which one you agreed with thats why I asked the clarifying question.

See https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/79314/word-study-g5546-%ce%a7%cf%81%ce%b9%cf%83%cf%84%ce%b9%ce%b1%ce%bd%e1%bd%b9%cf%82-christian%c3%b3s/79321#79321

@Dottard Thanks for the link, that was helpful. I noticed earlier you said we take the name of Christ but we are not equal to Christ. When you say "not equal", what do you mean?

We are not Christ - He is the Savior, Creator, sustainer, Great example to us, the great Shepherd of the church, Almighty God, perfect, sinless, the Lamb of God, etc.  We are none of these.

My understanding is that we will not receive His name exactly. Perhaps partially?
Sharing in His glory cannot equate to taking His name. However, as a wife takes her husbands name when they are wed, there is something happening there.
If we are to look at the angels, they all bear the name of God (El).
Micha-el, Gabri-el, Uri-el, Emmanu-el, Hal-el, Azaz-el etc..
In Revelation 2:17 - "And I will give him a white stone, and on the stone a new name written which no one knows except him who receives it.” ’
So it looks like everyone will be given a unique name by Messiah. Whether or not it is in addition to our current name is unknown.

Thank you for the response, that was my understanding as well. Inheritance cannot mean that we receive everything Christ has to the same degree/in the same way. It would seem that we receive the name to symbolize our allegiance/adoption by God, but it is not our name in the same way it is Christ's name - as for Christ it represents his authority above all.
